# Is there a common reporter class for both JUnit and TestNG?

Tags: java, junit, testng

I have 2 frameworks, one with Junit and one TestNG. I need a common custom report for both the frameworks. I don't want to  be maintaining code in both frameworks to retain the same format of reports for both.

Anyone know a common way to have custom reports for JUnit and TestNG?

Answer (score 1):

TestNG can be configured to output reports in the same format as JUnit, thereby unifying the reporting of your two frameworks.

If you're looking for something third-party, I'd recommend [ExtentReports](http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/), which is a bit more friendly to QA teams and with the logger style syntax, is very easy to implement in your tests.